# Alphabetic list with letter - clickable

Tags: android, listview, alphabetic

I am creating an alphabetic ordered list, where there is also a letter showing up above the items - see the image:
[image: screenshot]

This is already done and working fine, but I need to have each item clickable, except the letters.

This is a part of my code from MainActivity.java (fragment):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bohovia, container, false);

        List<LetterSectionListItem> books = createBooks();

        ListView bookListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.booklistview);

                LetterSectionListAdapter bookListAdapter = new LetterSectionListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.booklist_row, books) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
                //Must call this before to wrap the header around the view
                v = super.getView(position, v, parent);

                TextView bookTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
                TextView authorName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.author_name);

                Book book = (Book) this.getItem(position);

                assert book != null;
                bookTitle.setText(book.getBookName());
                authorName.setText(book.getAuthorLastName() + ", " + book.getAuthorFirstName());

                return v;
            }
        };

        bookListView.setAdapter(bookListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

**Now what I tried:**

I put there this code, just above `return rootView;` :

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),SingleitemView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("place2", "test");
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
```

However, this is working fine, so opens another activity after clicking the item, but also when I click the standalone letters, and I don't want to have clickable letters A, B, C.. etc., just the items below.

Can someone please advice here, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder that nobody could help with such easy thing! I solved it for myself, in my adapter I just used this:

```
   TextView headerLetterTextView = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_row_letter);
headerLetterTextView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OnItemClick and specify which item will be clickable

Comment: no sir, rather I'd use something like view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.items_menu_header, null);    
view.setOnClickListener(null); So this disables the clicks on the line I want, but then I think I need to enable the clicking again